# Why are querySelectorAll() and getElementsByTagName() not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select all `<a>` elements in an HTML page and then add a class to each of them. Then later run a function that removes this same class from each of the `<a>` elements.

I've tried to do it with querySelectorAll():

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').className += ' class1';
```

And with getElementsByTagName():

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a').className += ' class1';
```

But neither works. I've already got this working with jQuery so don't need an answer in that. I'd just looking to compare the performance of JavaScript vs. jQuery in this situation, and to learn more vanilla JavaScript while I'm at it.

I've also tried removing the class like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a").className =
  document.querySelectorAll("a").className.replace
    ( /(?:^|\s)class1(?!\S)/g , '' )
```

And:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a").className =
 document.getElementsByTagName("a").className.replace
  ( /(?:^|\s)class1(?!\S)/g , '' );
```

But neither of those work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They both return list, use a simple loop

Answer (score 2):

[`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list. You need to iterate over the list elements

Comment: Much thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a list, so you need to loop over it. Example:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    links[i].className = 'class1';
}
```